# Binding a datagrid to SQLite

Tags: wpf, sqlite

I am creating a test database using C# WPF & SQLite.  I am just about to add a datagrid to the form, which I want to be up-datable.  But I'm quite new to this and struggling.  Does anyone have any good websites/overviews as to how this should be done?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

add a datagrid with 2 columns to your app ui 
like this

```
 <DataGrid  Name="mydatagrid"   AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="300"  Width="400" Loaded="DataGrid_Loaded">
        <DataGrid.Columns>


            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="100" Binding="{Binding nam}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="password" Width="100" Binding="{Binding pas}"></DataGridTextColumn>



        </DataGrid.Columns>

    </DataGrid>
```

create sqlite database with a table named acc that contains name and password (nam,pass) then you need to insert a name and password

```
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Controls; 

public void creat_db()
{
 SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("e:\\MyDatabase.sqlite");
       var con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=e:\\MyDatabase.sqlite;");
        con.Open();
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE acc (nam STRING, pas STRING)";
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, con);
      command.ExecuteNonQuery();

string name = "joe",password="123";

  sql = ("insert into acc (nam,Pas)values('" + name + "','" + password + "')");

        SQLiteCommand insertcommand = new SQLiteCommand(sql, con);
        insertcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
}
```

view database on datagrid

```
public void refresh()
    {
        var con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=e:\\MyDatabase.sqlite;");
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            SQLiteCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM acc ";
            using (SQLiteDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, con))
            {
                DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

                mydatagrid.ItemsSource =  dataTable.AsDataView();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exp.Message);
        }

    }
```

refresh datagrid on load

```
  private void DataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       refresh();
    }
```

this sample shows how easy its done 
you can see this link for more options on datagrid binding 
[WPF-and-SQLite-Database](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/153407/WPF-and-SQLite-Database)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you need, but it may help you 
[Microsoft Step by Step](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg606540%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX)

Comment: Thanks for that - really useful for future reference.

Answer (score -2):

I found a really good page that gave me what I needed:

[How to bind your datagrid](http://www.studyoverflow.org/2013/06/how-to-bind-datagrid-using-datatable.html)

Comment: Link broken. Always a good idea to show the code that helped you. A link may or may not be there in future.